# Prisma returning error of expected input type but type is provided

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma

I'm struggling with the Prisma API, maybe I'm confusing a little, when I try to query by some field of the model which is a unique field, and using playground I got an error. Let me put in context.

```
type Organization {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    staff: [Employee!]!
}

type Query {
    organization(id: ID!): Organization!
    organizations: [Organization]!
    organizationByName(name: String!):Organization! //This is the one with the error
}
```

This is the prisma datamodel

```
type Organization {
    id: ID! @unique
    name: String! @unique
    staff: [Employee!]!
}
```

and this is the prisma schema generated (the part that are for interest)

```
input OrganizationWhereUniqueInput {
  id: ID
  name: String
}
```

finally, the resolver:

```
function organizationByName(parent, {name}, context, info) {
  return context.prisma.organization({name: name});
}
```

When I hit the query:

```
query{
  organizationByName(nombre:"Bitas"){
    id
    name
  }
}
```

I got the error:

*Reason: 'name' Field 'name' is not defined in the input type* **'OrganizationWhereUniqueInput'**

but as you can see on the generated schema, there is a name field... so I'm confused, could please somebody point me to the right direction, I'm newbie to GraphQL

Note: Also if I wanna resolve using where clause, I got the kinda same error but something like *where field* is not defined in the input type

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you are using `nombre: "Bitas"` instead of `name: "Bitas"`

Comment: You are running a query against the Prisma endpoint, and not against the endpoint that uses the schema you defined.